# SOQL slow query performance on FieldPermissions

Tags: soql, soap-api, bulk-api

I am running two jobs for Bulk API on FieldPermissions:

**Job 1:**

```
SELECT Id, ParentId, SobjectType, Field, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsRead, SystemModstamp FROM FieldPermissions WHERE SystemModstamp <= 2017-05-15T19:58:37Z
```

**Job 2:**

```
SELECT Id FROM FieldPermissions WHERE SystemModstamp <= 2017-05-15T20:30:28Z
```

Job 1 ran within 15 seconds while Job 2 is slow and running for about half an hour. Same set of job properties that is queried but I don't see why this is taking so long. Tried with SOAP API too for which the query on Job2 is really slow. How to speed up the SOQL on Job 2?

Comment: Is this a repeatable phenomenon? Seems like just a one-off.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [Query on FieldPermissions object is super slow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/124211/102). You need to include one of the indexed fields `SobjectType`, `Field`, or `PermissionsRead`

Comment: @DanielBallinger Wrong! Querying on Id alone with SystemModStamp is on the indexed field and the plan does not yield any warnings. Using PermissionsRead in the where clause would give the warning for unindexed field.

Comment: @dmachop I am seeing the Index on SystemModstamp. Oddly, the TableScan is coming up first in the Query Plan. If so, that would certainly explain whey the query is so slow. Can you check what your query plan comes up with.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Same [query plan](https://imgur.com/a/Yb57Sti). It's odd as it is stuck only for FieldPermissions.

Comment: Anyone has luck on this, I am also having the same issue, it is taking ages to load fieldpermissions for one object.